# Unable to build Puppeteer-Sharp on MacOS, Jan-2021

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, puppeteer-sharp

have tried to build the [Puppeteer Sharp project](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp) on my mac machine and failed in a somehow strange way.
After cloning the repo, creating [test server certificate](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) and installing .Net Core SDK 2.2.207.
I tried to build the solution within the lib folder:

`dotnet build PuppeteerSharp.sln`

The build starts and fails in, AFAIK corect way

```
  Restore completed in 115.15 ms for *****/workspace/puppeteer-sharp/lib/PuppeteerSharp.Tests.DumpIO/PuppeteerSharp.Tests.DumpIO.csproj.
  Restore completed in 117.49 ms for *****/workspace/puppeteer-sharp/lib/PuppeteerSharp.DevicesFetcher/PuppeteerSharp.DevicesFetcher.csproj.
  Restore completed in 160.85 ms for *****/workspace/puppeteer-sharp/lib/PuppeteerSharp.Tests/PuppeteerSharp.Tests.csproj.
  Restore completed in 4.54 ms for *****/workspace/puppeteer-sharp/lib/PuppeteerSharp/PuppeteerSharp.csproj.
  PuppeteerSharp.TestServer -> *****/workspace/puppeteer-sharp/lib/PuppeteerSharp.TestServer/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/PuppeteerSharp.TestServer.dll
FrameManager.cs(102,50): error CS0121: 
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
'System.Collections.Generic.CollectionExtensions.GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>, TKey)' and
'PuppeteerSharp.Helpers.DictionaryExtensions.GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, TKey)'
[*****/workspace/puppeteer-sharp/lib/PuppeteerSharp/PuppeteerSharp.csproj]
...
```

There are several other errors with similar reasons.

My question what can I do to build the project?
The ambiguous reference is valid, the [.Net package](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/CollectionExtensions.cs) does implements the same extension method as the [puppeteer-sharp helper class](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/blob/master/lib/PuppeteerSharp/Helpers/DictionaryExtensions.cs) and both are referenced in the [FrameManager.cs class](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/blob/master/lib/PuppeteerSharp/FrameManager.cs)

THX Murx

Comment: It build for me locally. Can you try `dotnet build ./PuppeteerSharp/PuppeteerSharp.csproj`?

Comment: HI, same problem still ambiguous references on the path. Maybe my Kung-Sharp is to bad, is there a possibility to force the compiler to prefer internal/assembly extension methods over library methods?